# Windows 10 audio stuttering/cracking issues

Tags: windows-10, audio, dpc

I know there are quite a few threads open for this issue but after hours of research and trial and error I haven't found a solution yet. Plus I'm not that much into the internals of Windows and can't really figure out what all those captured data means.

The issue is simple: I often hear a loud cracking sound when I move over menu entries in game which cause short sound effects like a single "click" sound. This happens more or less frequent and becomes annoying quickly. Moreover I realized that those short sounds often don't play as intended. If you move over quickly you hear a click sound for each menu entry, sometimes you hear nothing at all for 1-2 seconds and then you hear it fade in and work as intended.

Same goes for VLC player - when I move around the timeline quickly you often hear the cracking when the video starts playing again after "jumping".

I tested with LatencyMon and got a highest DPC latency of *2557 us* with a message that my system couldn't handle realtime audio.

So things I already tried:

- Updated BIOS to latest version
- Tried disabling HPET (though in Windows 10 this seems to be a resolved issue since HPET only runs for specific applications)
- Updated all drivers
- Various other things in the BIOS which did not help

And now for the data. I got the following:

- [LatencyMon Report](https://pastebin.com/C4yaJ1Rf)
- [XPerf DPC Report](https://pastebin.com/8rJrdHvr)
- [DxDiag Report](https://pastebin.com/TPb4vXGN)
- [Driverquery Report](https://pastebin.com/rMtGh6df)

As far as I understand the most troublesome drivers seem to be the Realtek HD Audio driver and the DirectX Kernel.

Little side-note: I had a SoundBlaster ZX a time ago which I sent back. The card had - though it should move audio processing to the sound card instead doing it on the CPU - the same issues with cracking sounds.

Moreover the Windows installation is quite fresh (beginning of June) so there shouldn't be much issues from cluttering.

EDIT: My PC specs are the following (it should handle that well enough)

- i5 6600K 4C @ 4.7 Ghz
- AMD Radeon R9 290
- 16GB DDR4-3000 RAM
- System drive SSD 256GB
- AsRock Z170 Extreme 4+ MoBo

Comment: the xperf report shows no issues. I need to look at the generated ETL file to see more.

Comment: any update? Have you uploaded the ETL which was generated via xperf?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue with my Dell laptop. But much more severe, actions like closing a medium sized application would cause audio stutter.

Drivers were already up to date.

The only thing I've found that seems to work is disabling fast boot. Apparently a real / full reboot fixes certain problems with interrupt handling. And that's important because if the sound hardware is asking for more audio samples the system should respond in a timely fashion.

So you could try to disable the following (reversible) setting followed by a reboot.

[image: Disable fast startup]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out when I'm home!

Comment: This seems to have helped me man, thanks for sharing!

Comment: A problem never comes alone. In my case there was also really aggressive end point protection software with network packet inspection & AV that slowed down interrupt handling on network interfaces. LatencyMon can help uncover these mysteries.